# Algorithm to keep collection sorted while inserting in the middle

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have a large collection of elements.
Each element has a "position" field, which is a positive integer.
No two elements have the same value for the field "position".

The only supported operation of the collection is: addElement(newElement, positionAfterElement), where:
 - newElement is the new element to be added (its position is unknown for now)
 - positionAfterElement is an existing element of the collection.

The function will guarantee that:
 - position(positionAfterElement) < position(newElement)
 - no other element in the collection has a position between position(positionAfterElement) and position(newElement)

I can change the value of all the element positions as I wish but I want to minimize the number of changes (on average).

How should I implement the addElement function?

I could just push all the elements with higher positions by 1 but I am pretty sure there must be a better way to do this.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: I smell homework, retagging now.

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail to adequately answer your question.  Obvious outstanding questions are: what kind of data structure are these in? How is it initially populated with elements, and are their initial positions sparse, or dense?  Do you prefer a better average time for adding an element, or a better worst-case time?

Comment: Well try something yourself. If you have problem with the code you can ask here.

Comment: Absolutely not homework! What makes you think that?
I prefer better amortized time, as there will be many many insertions.
I am not sure the data structure really matters. Let's just say I can access any element in constant time. In practice, the elements will be spread accross many servers.

Comment: Data structure definitely matters.  You'll have a very different set of issues if your backing data structure is an array than if it's a linked list.

Comment: So I cannot store all my elements on the same server. I can only access any element (to read or modify its position) in constant time.

Comment: @EA: From your comments it looks as if the data structure cannot be changed, and works for all intents and purposes as an array. Unless the underlying data structure is changed (e.g. to a BST/other sorted structure), I don't think there is any possible improvement on your solution.

Comment: The data structure cannot be changed but the way we allocate the values in the field "position" can. Allocating positions every ten (10, 20, 30, ...), instead of (1, 2, 3, ...) already gives you an "on-average" improvement, I think. 

I am just wondering if there is some kind of best practice or best algorithm to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here is what I implemented, in pseudo-code:

```
addElement(newElement, positionAfterElement):
    p0 <- positionOf(positionAfterElement)
    c <- 5
    finished <- false
    while (not finished):
        search for all elements which positions are in the range [p0 + 1, p0 + c]
        if there are less than c elements in that range:  // the range is not full
            adjust position of elements in the range, and position of newElement,
            so that
              - elements are correctly ordered
              - element positions are "evenly spread out" within the range
            finished <- true
        else:                                             // the range is full
            c <- c * 2
    end while
end addElement
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a balanced tree.  At every node of the tree, keep a count of the number of items below it (left.count + right.count + 1).  Then, you can compute the index of an item easily while traversing to it.  This is O(n log n) time in the number of operations.

Comment: really, how? for what?
the question is to determine the value of the field "position"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic idea:

```
expected_number_of_elements = 10^6
spread_factor = 100
first element gets position = spread_factor * expected_number_of_element
each following element inserted:
    if its inserted in last position, give it the last element's position + spread_factor
    if its inserted in the first position, give it the first element's position - spread_factor
    otherwise, put it in the middle between its 2 closest neighbors
    if you don't have any space left: expand_the_array


expand_the_array:
    spread_factor = spread_factor * 10
    iterate over all the elements, and multiply position by 10.
```

expanding the array is an expensive operation, but since it multiplies the size of the array, on average (assuming your input is random, and not crafted by an adversary) you'll have to do this operation very rarely.

the major drawback of this solution, is that you'll have to watch out for int overflow....